# How do I test a component in Angular that with a helper method that requires TranslateService?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, angular-test, ngx-translate

I have a custom Validator that uses ngx-translate

```
export class CustomValidator {
  static translation: TranslateService;

  static setTranslationService( translation: TranslateService): void {
    CustomValidator.translation = translation;
  }

  static required(messageKey: string = 'COMMON.VALIDATORS.REQUIRED') {
    const message = this.translation.instant(messageKey);
    return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
      return control.value ? null : { required: message };
    };
  }
}
```

I am setting the translateService in my app.component, like so:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private translateService: TranslateService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    CustomValidator.setTranslationService(this.translateService);
  }
}
```

and it works, but then when it comes to testing any component that uses the CustomValidator, I get an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'instant')
```

I have tried creating a MockCustomValidator class and adding it as a provider

```
describe('MainLayoutComponent', () => {
  let component: MainLayoutComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MainLayoutComponent>;
    
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        TranslateTestingModule.withTranslations({
          en: require('../../../../../assets/i18n/en.json'),
        })
      ], providers: [
        { provide: CustomValidator, useClass: MockCustomValidator }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MainLayoutComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
}
```

but it still throws the error. Any idea how I should approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I managed to solve it, not with the by mocking the custom validator but by mocking TranslateService with a instant method and making this changes to my test:

```
describe('MainLayoutComponent', () => {
    let component: MainLayoutComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<MainLayoutComponent>;
    
    beforeEach(async () => {
      await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
          TranslateTestingModule.withTranslations({
            en: require('../../../../../assets/i18n/en.json'),
          })
        ]
      }).compileComponents();
    });

    beforeEach(() => {
      CustomValidator.setTranslationService(new MockTranslateService());
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MainLayoutComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create', () => {
      expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
}
```

the downside is that inside the CustomValidator I had to change the type from TranslateService to type any, in order to be able set the mock class instead